# having trouble normalizing this database

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Currently, I have 48 fields. 
[image]

I'm completely new to access. This is how I decided to connect everything together.

[image]

It doesn't seem to be very effective. Could somebody help me understand how to normalize this database?

Should I try to put employee information in one table, job information in another table and then have an equipment lookup table?

Comment: You need to account for the various entities, then determine the relationship between them. Based on what you have shown, I would have the 'Employee' table with current info; then would have a related table for prior/current job (set a flag indicating current); you don't mention if equipment is related to the job so I assume it is, thus create an equipment table and relate to either employee or to employee job. <stepping on soap box> the function of a relational database is not to eliminate redundancy... it is to LIMIT redundancy...

Comment: Is there a way to merge the current/past jobs into one key? For example, is there a way to detect if past or current by the date?

Comment: I suggest an 'AutoNumber' key for each table. That maintains a unique identifier for every record in every table. Then look at all the attributes of a job - nut just current but past. That means the 'Jobs' table has start, end, min & max salary, title, etc. One way to indicate current is the absence of an end date, or you could have a flag stating 'current', or you could use the most current start date. Map out the relationships as 'one to one' or 'one to many'. 1-1 you could consider including the fields in one table, else create related table.

Comment: I'm sorry, not understanding what you are saying. Complete noob here. :(

Comment: I'm willing to help, but since this is your homework, you need to get your hands a little dirty, and learn to ask specific questions. saying you are 'not understanding' covers a lot of ground. My suggestion: (1) Create Employee table; (2) Create Equipment table; (3) Create Jobs table. (4) Create Dept table; No relationship between any tables yet! (5) Create EmpJob table with three keys & relate to Emp & Job & Dept tables; (6) Create EmpEquip table with two keys & relate to EMP & Equip tables (w/2 keys again).  (7) Post your table designs and relationships.

Answer (score 0):

The current job, last job, and previous job can all the SAME table. If you sort this table by descending job start date, then then you have current, last and previous. You thus don’t need nor want a separate table for each of these which really amounts to the concept of a “job”. If sorting by date is not enough, then you could add a column called Job Type (current, previous, etc.). Again, we still only using the one table.

The same goes for Equipment. You really don’t care if the limit is 3 last, or 300 last. By building a normalized table, then ONE form can edit all types and you save MASSIVE amounts of coding and building of tables, User interface software, and that of building quires to retrieve + show the last 3 jobs in a form.

The fact that your design with FAR LESS cost of development allows 3 or 300 last jobs is really moot. More important if some manager comes along and now wants you to save the last 4 jobs, you don’t have some massive re-design here. And you can on the fly add new job types. So in place of current, and say previous, you can also have un-completed, or failed jobs. So adding new business rules means again you don’t add a new type of job table, but only a “type” to the one column you already using to define the job as current or previous.

Comment: You could also have a start/end date for jobs - the current job will be the one with a null end date.

Answer (score 0):

1. Identify like objects and make one table to store all of them.  In your design you have three tables for equipment but each item of equipment has the same fields; they should be one table.  Similarly for jobs, each job is pretty much the same; they should be one table.  The same for departments.
2. Figure out one or more column in each table that can uniquely identify the row in the table (that is, if you know the values for those columns it is *impossible* for there ever to be two rows with those values).  These are your primary keys for your tables.
3. Identify cases in which an item in one table needs to "point to" (refer to) an item in another table.  In this case, make sure that the referring table has a set of columns that match the referred-to table.

When you've done that, you'll have the beginnings of a correctly factored relational database design.